# Javascript passing parameter syntax issue

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am making a div clickable using Onlick Event of  tag. Then also passing a parameter when a div is clicked.
I am facing issue while passing a parameter from one JS method to another.

```html
<a href="#" Onclick="callmethod1(a.b.c.1.0.1);" <div id="test"> </div></a>
```

```html
  callmethod1(parameter){
    //definition goes on here
    }
```

While calling the method with parameter, it shows 
Documents.aspx:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Post the full code, please along with content of `onclick` attribute, please.

Comment: Can you please help now Adam? I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than one issue to fix:

- Anchor `<a>` tags cannot have block elements like `<div>`
- `<a>` it is not closed; the first part of it, and the attribute is `onclick` not `onlcick`

  ```
  <a href="#" onclick="callmethod1(a.b.c.1.0.1);">
                                        _________^
  ```
- Function parameters (arguments) cannot be like `a.b.c.1.0.1`. I would assume you are trying to pass a string `"a.b.c.1.0.1"`
- Functions definition must be prefixed with `function` or `var fnName = function()`

  ```
  function callmethod1(parameter){
       // function
  }
  ```

Fixed snippet

```js
function callmethod1(parameter){
   console.log(parameter);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="callmethod1('a.b.c.1.0.1');">Click<a>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Adam. Click was a typo here when I posted the question, I have more than 5 divs each should be clickable and hence i have wrapped each div by anchor tag. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use CSS to make `a` full block inside the parent `div`. I would like to see a real example of what you're trying to achieve to give you a better suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter is a string, you should embrace them with single quotes:

```
<a href="#" Onlcick="callmethod1('a.b.c.1.0.1');" <div id="test"> </div></a>
```